# Expect array to be between fixed size Typescript using tuples?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes in an argument of the shape `Record<string, number[]>` where the array can be between 1 and 2 numbers.

I'm having trouble restricting this to 1 or 2 and have tried the following:

```js
const obj = { 'a': [0, 10], 'b': [11, 20], 'c': [21] };
function bar({data}: DataShape) {}

type DataShape = {
  data: Record<string, [number, number?]> 
}
const foo = bar({ data: obj }) 
// Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, (number | undefined)?]'.
// Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer

// -------------------------------------------------------------
// Tried creating two defined tuple types
type DataShape = {
  data: Record<string, [number, number] | [number]> 
}
const foo = bar({ data: obj })
// Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
// Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

But can't get the crossover of `number[]` to a `[number]` tuple to work. Is there a way to restrict the `number[]` with `1...n`?

Comment: The default type inferred for `obj` is too loose for your purposes.  You could use a `const` assertion [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLqo2W) and things will work for you.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this does work quite well, thank you. Is there still a way to do this without modifying the obj itself? Asking as this is for a library I have and the consumer passes in this object as an instantiation value, and it'd be nice to just have them not need worrying about doing the assertion themself.

Comment: No, without the const assertion or something like it, the consumer is throwing away the information (well, the compiler is doing it on the consumer's behalf) before giving the object to your library.  You can't "un-dispose" of the information that's gone, so you're stuck.  Do you still want to see me write up an answer here?

Comment: @jcalz okay yeah that makes sense. I'll just amend the docs to include this. you can just leave it as this comment here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a type for the array, and constrain `obj` like:

```
type MyArray = [number, number?]

const obj: Record<string, MyArray> = { 'a': [0, 10], 'b': [11, 20], 'c': [21] };

function bar({data}: DataShape) {}

type DataShape = {
  data: Record<string, MyArray> 
}

const foo = bar({ data: obj })
```